# Erasing a vector element by key

Tags: c++, vector, encapsulation, friend

ive defined the following and filled it with elements:

```
vector <vector<double> > my_vector;
```

but i want a delete an element with a specific key...

```
my_vector.erase(int(specific_key));
```

but it doesnt allow me. how would i properly dispose of the elements assigned to that key properly?

Comment: there are no keys in vectors, only indices...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming by `specific_key` you mean the element at that position in the `vector`:

```
my_vector.erase(my_vector.begin() + specific_key);
```

Would be the "most correct" answer.

If you meant to delete the element that matches `specific_key` (which will have to be of type `vector<double>` in the given example:

```
my_vector.erase(find(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), specific_key));
```

Comment: yes i want to delete the element at that position in the vector. when i apply the code you gabe (first one), my application freezes.

Comment: never mind the freeze was caused by something else. will test this once i get the freezing fixed.

Comment: +1, for both the options. Be sure that you check for end() before erasing.

Answer (score 1):

erase takes in an iterator as argument.

You can do

```
my_vector.erase (my_vector.begin() + specific_key);
```

You can also pass in a range

```
my_vector.erase (my_vector.begin(), my_vector.begin() + 2);
```

One thing that you should note is that the size of the vector also gets reduced.

Answer (score 0):

The erase method takes iterators as their argument.

[Example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

Answer (score 0):

If Specific key is not position and say its some data in vector, then one has to iterate vector for that data and erase particular iterator.